# Something is wrong with folders containing special characters

Tags: command-line, directory, special-characters

I can create folder with special characters (example `mkdir Öäväaä`), but ls -l in terminal shows `??v?a?`.

WinScp and mc shows it right (Öäväaä). How can i make terminal to show me right characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what terminal you're using, but if you're using the default one in Ubuntu you should be able to edit the terminal settings and change the encoding. Since it's a problem isolated to the terminal app, it's probably a setting error, and most likely encoding.

I'm not running Ubuntu right now so I'm not sure where it's located, but I'm pretty sure it's somewhere around Edit > Preferences or similar, around where you change things like background color and font for the terminal. I'd suggest switching to UTF-8 and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: That would be `Terminal` (I'm talking about the menu item called `Terminal`) > `Set Character Encoding`.

Comment: Yup, that's it.